# Расширяемое приложение с многоуровневой архитектурой

Tags: angularjs, архитектура, asp.net-web-api

Необходимо сделать расширяемое приложение, используя многоуровневую архитектуру. Приложение будет использовать *ms sql* и активно использовать хранимые процедуры.

Есть инструмент ADO.NET Entity Data Model там автоматически создаётся модель и context. И потом на базе этого я делаю интерфейс и на базе него делаю класс по интерфейсу. Пока писал кое что понял, но есть всё ровно не понятки. Как от кого что куда переводить. Чем их обеднять и как разделить на уровни. Хочу именно пример живой увидеть. Ещё видел что model выводят в Core а Context на верхний уровень ,в этот компонент создаёт Model.edmx и там и model и context вместе их что вручную раскидывать по уровням. В общем сами взаимосвязи классов не понятны.

Comment: А проблема-то в чём? Вроде сам всё нормально описал.